# How to detect whether a delayed job is currently working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, delay, delayed-job

I have a form through which I am uploading images. The workflow is, that I will upload and save an image and then I run a delayed job, that will take this image and will create from it 3 thumbs.

When I refresh the page, I usually see that the thumbs are not created yet, but after a while (10-15 seconds) are the thumbs ready.

But this is not very friendly - I would like to show to a user that his thumb is in progress of creating, but how to do that?

The structure of the **delayed_jobs** table is like this:

```
  create_table "delayed_jobs", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "priority",   :default => 0, :null => false
    t.integer  "attempts",   :default => 0, :null => false
    t.text     "handler",                   :null => false
    t.text     "last_error"
    t.datetime "run_at"
    t.datetime "locked_at"
    t.datetime "failed_at"
    t.string   "locked_by"
    t.string   "queue"
    t.datetime "created_at",                :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                :null => false
  end
```

I think the way to go could be to add to this table a column, like **photo_id** and simply if the respective row would be missing in this table, then I would know that the thumb is ready. Otherwise is in a queue/in progress of creating.

But how to save into this table this extra column? When I call the **delay** method, it's just like this:

```
@user.delay.activate!(@device)
```

How to pass there an **ID** of a photo?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Rather than storing the `photo_id` in the `delayed_jobs` table, you can store the job id in the `photos` (or `users`) table. For this you'll need to write a Job class like so:

```
class PhotoThumbnailJob < Struct.new(:user_id)

  def perform
    # generate the thumbnail
  end

end
```

Then get a reference to the job instance like this:

```
job = Delayed::Job.enqueue(PhotoThumbnailJob.new(@user.id))
@user.thumbnail_job_id = job.id
```

Now as long as you have the @user you can get the job. That way you can tell whether it failed or simply hasn't finished yet, and if it failed you can report on the reason, etc.

Note that if you do this, you might want to create a foreign key constraint on thumbnail_job_id and tell it to null that column when the job is deleted, because by default DJ will delete successful jobs from the delayed_jobs table.

Answer (score 0):

I had a need for a similar capability in an application I built. The approach I took was to use WebSockets to send status updates to the user as my DelayedJob jobs progress. I used [Pusher](http://pusher.com/) because the API is straightforward and it was free for us, but any implementation, including your own, would do.

Otherwise, I would stay very far way from altering the table and instead utilize the various hooks DelayedJob provides to enable a callback capability for you to take whatever action you prefer at various stages of the job.